# Time complexity difference between 2 solutions for Min Cost Climbing Stairs

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Min Cost Climbing Stairs problem is defined here: https://leetcode.com/problems/min-cost-climbing-stairs/

I have 2 solutions for this - 1 that takes 1ms to run on the leetcode submission and is faster than 89.65% of Java submissions and the 2nd that takes 2ms and is faster than only 39.33% of the Java submissions on Leetcode.
I need help figuring out how are the solutions so drastically different in terms of time complexity when they look similar to each other. There must be some nuance I am missing which I want to better understand.

I am sharing the 2 solutions below:

1. Executes in 1ms and is faster than 89.65% of Java submissions:

```
    public int minCostClimbingStairs(int[] cost) {
        // The array's length should be 1 longer than the length of cost
        // This is because we can treat the "top floor" as a step to reach
        int minimumCost[] = new int[cost.length + 1];
        
        // Start iteration from step 2, since the minimum cost of reaching
        // step 0 and step 1 is 0
        for (int i = 2; i < minimumCost.length; i++) {
            int takeOneStep = minimumCost[i - 1] + cost[i - 1];
            int takeTwoSteps = minimumCost[i - 2] + cost[i - 2];
            minimumCost[i] = Math.min(takeOneStep, takeTwoSteps);
        }
        
        // The final element in minimumCost refers to the top floor
        return minimumCost[minimumCost.length - 1];
    }
```

2. Executes in 2ms and is faster than 39.33% of Java submissions:

```
    public int minCostClimbingStairs(int[] cost) {
        //cost: 0 ->n-1
        //dp: 1->n
        int[] dp = new int[cost.length+1];
        dp[0]=0;
        dp[1]=0;
        //k=2
        for(int i=1;i<cost.length;i++) {
            dp[i+1] = cost[i] + Math.min(dp[i], dp[i-1]);
        }
        
        return Math.min(dp[cost.length], dp[cost.length-1]);
        
    }
```

Comment: Seems like the second one is executing more constant operations + an extra iteration on the loop of the algorithm. But I really don't know why is that big of a difference here ☹️

Comment: Perhaps they only time with ms resolution? I wouldn't get too excited -- do your own proper benchmarking.

Comment: @tgdavies - sure will do.

Comment: Looks like time measurement inaccuracy. You can try resubmitting both solutions several times and see what happens.